# Symfony2 Doctrine Join Entity

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

I have a entity with the next join:

```
class blogComment
{
    ....

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BlogComment", mappedBy="replyTo")
     */
    protected $replies;

    ....
}
```

Now I get successfully all the replies. But I only want to get: `where active = true`

How to do that?

Oke if you guys recommend to get the comments by query in the controller how to build a nested array to get result like this:

[image: Nested comments]

Comment: Take a look at the FOSCommentBundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle

Answer (score 3):

For solving the part where you only want active replies there are a couple of options:

1) Use some custom DQL in a repository:

```
$dql = 'SELECT bc FROM BlogComment bc WHERE bc.replyTo = :id AND bc.active = :active';
$q = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setParameters(array('id' => $id, 'active' => true));
```

2) Using `ArrayCollection::filter()` in the getter:

```
public function getReplies()
{
    return $this->replies
        ->filter(function ($reply) {
            return $reply->isActive();
        })
        ->toArray();
}
```

3) Using `ArrayCollection::matching()` ([Collection Criteria API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)) in the getter:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

// ...

public function getReplies()
{
    $criteria = new Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('active', true));

    return $this->replies
        ->matching($criteria)
        ->toArray();
}
```

4) Use [Filters](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html). These can add where clauses to queries regardless of where that query is generated. Please see the [docs](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html).

If you want to be able to fetch an entire set of replies, nested and all, in a single query, you need to implement some kind of "tree" of "nested set" functionality. I'd advise you to look at the [Tree](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) behavior of [l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions).

Answer (score 0):

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Wherever you are obtaining your blog comments to display them (probably on a controller), you need to customise your query so that only the active replies are extracted.  Something like:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT b FROM blogComment b JOIN b.replies r WHERE r.active = :active');
$query->setParameter('active', true);
$blogComments = $query->getResult();
```

EDIT:

For your new requirement of nested replies, you would need to specify a relationship between a comment entity and its parent comment.